# Convert exception to optional: cant resolve overloaded function type

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm trying to build a generic function that converts exceptions to optional:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto get_opt(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    auto ret = std::experimental::optional<decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>();
    try
    {
        ret = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    catch(const std::exception&)
    {}

    return ret;
}
```

i then can use it with any function that might throw an exception, and it works fine for functions with no overloads:

```
int test(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::stoi(s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto n = get_opt(test, "1234");

    if(n)
    {
        std::cout << "value: " << *n << std::endl;
    }
}
```

problem is if i use a function that has overloads, the compiler complains he doesnt know what overload to call:

```
auto n = get_opt(std::to_string, 1234);

main.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to 'get_opt(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)'
```

this one should call the `std::to_string(int)` overload.

1. Is my `get_opt` function well formed? is the universal reference for `args` and using `std::forward` the way to go for this case?
2. Why cant the compiler see what overload to call given that the arguments `int` were passed, he should figure the correct overload right?
3. How can I make it work for overloads?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with template type deduction, and is one of the perfect forwarding failures. When you have an overloaded function, which one of them is supposed to be deduced for `Func`?

There are two ways around this. Either, create a function pointer of the correct type and pass it in, or just cast `to_string` to that type:

```
using FuncType = std::string(*)(int );
FuncType f = std::to_string;

auto n = get_opt(f, 1234); 
auto n2 = get_opt(static_cast<FuncType>(std::to_string), 1234);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. it makes perfect sense that it cant deduce Func, for some reason i thought the compiler could use the Args for that, but obviously he cant. The cast works, but i would like to make it cleaner, i tried: template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
auto get_opt(Ret(*f)(Args...), Args&&... args) and then i would call the function like this: auto n = get_opt<std::string>(std::to_string, 1234); but i get the exact same error. but now he should be able to deduce the function right? i give him the return type and the arguments types.

Comment: @sap Same reason. `std::to_string` does not have a type. No type == no type deduction, so there's no way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my `get_opt` function well formed? is the universal reference for args and using `std::forward` the way to go for this case?

Yes.

> Why cant the compiler see what overload to call given that the arguments int were passed, he should figure the correct overload right?

The compiler won't check the function call to see which overload should be chosen. The fact is that when you have an overloaded function, referencing that function solely by its name causes an ambiguity because there are multiple functions it could be. It is in fact an "unresolved overloaded function type".

You can normally get around this by casting to the correct type, but if you function uses template argument deduction you won't be able to achieve that at the call site inside `get_opt`. You can solve that with a lambda expression:

```
auto glambda = [&] (auto&& x) { return std::to_string(x); });
auto n = get_opt(glambda, 1234);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i guess theres no other way. now all i need is a generic function that returns a lambda for any given function! oh wait...

Comment: @sap can do it with a macro.